# Vuforia Sample App Error

Tags: android, eclipse, vuforia

I am new to vuforia. I am trying to run the sample app but getting the following error:

> DataSet.STORAGE_TYPE.STORAGE_APPRESOURCE

It says

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   STORAGE_TYPE cannot be resolved or is not a field   CylinderTargets.java    /VuforiaSamples/src/com/qualcomm/vuforia/samples/VuforiaSamples/app/CylinderTargets line 327    Java Problem

Can anyone direct on how to resolve this. I am getting this issue in CylinderTargets.java, ImageTargets.java, UserDefinedTargets.java. 
I am developing it using Eclipse on a Windows7 operating system. Can someone please guide me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

remove your exsisting vuforia lib and add the one which is given with the vuforia sample android projects

in eclipse right click the project goto properties -> java build path 
 select the Libraries tab 
click on vuforia and click remove button on the right side.

now click add externa Libraries and browse to the android sample project path

vuforia-sdk-android-2-8-7\build\java\vuforia\vuforia.jar

version mine is (2-8-7) you my have a different one

or you can down load this and use it

http://we.tl/hTeANCJ2RZ

Comment: Thanks hari for your answer.